# can you customize a Google Maps display

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

[image: sample image]

Ignore the Hide|Show bar in the upper right hand corner.  It was present in the image I screen grabbed for this example.

Google adds the following:

- Google icon on the bottom left corner.
- Text on the bottom right corner.
- The little yellow man icon, + and - at the bottom of the right hand margin.
- The zoom icon at the top right corner.

Is it possible to hide any or all of these programmatically?

Comment: If you plan to screw with the copyright then anticipate getting your Google account and domain blocked

Comment: truthfully i seriously didn't expect google to be ok with that but i've been wrong about what i thought were sure things before

Comment: It's in their TOS you may get away with it for a very long time or short depends when someone reports it.

Comment: @Darknum i am not so starved for screen space that i need to do anything like that.  my client asked, i said i had a suspicion it wouldn't fly but would seek to verify.  i'm calling this verified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not really supposed to hide or remove the logo + copyright info but you can remove the controls by using `disableDefaultUI: true`.

Example:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
}
```

More info can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: You can also turn then on/off individually

Comment: @McMurphy that's good to know.  right now, my use case is all or nothing.  we'll see what the UI designer says when they see the all or nothing solution